# unlink and DELETE FROM won't work

Tags: php, mysqli, unlink

I'm trying to delete a folder from my server directory. It contains one image. The filesystem works something like: 'www/comics/0/page1.jpg' wherein I would want to eliminate '0'. (www is the root directory where all the PHP site scripts are). I'm also trying to delete the comic from the database. The comic is referred to by any pages tagged with its comicID as a foreign key.

My question is how to get unlink/DELETE FROM to actually do their jobs. Currently the site is throwing up no errors when run and cycles through the pages correctly, but fails to delete anything. It should be noted that I can delete individual pages with no issue.

A couple of notes:

- A comic with no pages will be deleted from the database but its folder will remain in the file system.
- A comic with pages doesn't do anything and remains in both database and file system.
- A comic with no file directory will be deleted from the database. (File directory is created upon creation of the first page).
- comicsID is taking a number value from comicsList, a select dropdown list. Here it should be '0' or so on, the ID of the comic selected for deletion and the name of its folder.

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['btnEdit']))
{
    $_SESSION['comicID'] = $_POST['comicsList'];
}

if(isset($_POST['btnDelete']))
{
    $_SESSION['comicID'] = $_POST['comicsList'];
    $setComic = $_SESSION['comicID'];
    include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');

    unlink(comics/$setComic);
    mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM comic WHERE comicID = '$setComic'");
    mysqli_close($conn);
    header('Location: myComics.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: 'folder', not 'fodler'. Sorry.

Comment: Try `unlink("comics/$setComic/$the_image");` then `rmdir("comics/$setComic");` - `$the_image` is a made up variable; you'll need to replace it with the image's name/variable.

Comment: Update: Doing `$image = "file.jpg"; $setComic = "0"; unlink("comics/$setComic/$image"); rmdir("comics/$setComic");` worked for me, so that's what you need to do/use.

Comment: is it working now ??.

Answer (score 1):

This is the logic you need to use:

```
$image = "file.jpg";
$setComic = "0";
unlink("comics/$setComic/$image");
rmdir("comics/$setComic");
```

As per [my comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308959/unlink-and-delete-from-wont-work#comment43079884_27308967)

*"You first need to delete all the files (or selected files) then remove the folder. [**unlink**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) doesn't do both actions."*

- [**rmdir**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) removes a directory but *only works* on **empty** folders.
- [**unlink**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) deletes a file, it doesn't delete folders.

Pulled from http://www.paulund.co.uk/php-delete-directory-and-files-in-directory

After all the files have been deleted then it can remove the directory by using the rmdir function.

```
<?php
function delete_directory($dirname) {
         if (is_dir($dirname))
           $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
     if (!$dir_handle)
          return false;
     while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
           if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
                     unlink($dirname."/".$file);
                else
                     delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);
           }
     }
     closedir($dir_handle);
     rmdir($dirname);
     return true;
}
?>
```

Cleaner Version By Lewis Cowles

After seeing this PHP snippet Lewis went away and improved the code by reducing it to only 9 lines of code. This is great when people take these snippets and improve them as it helps everyone learn a bit more about the code.

Here's the snippet that Lewis was able to come up with.

```
<?php
/* 
 * php delete function that deals with directories recursively
 */
function delete_files($target) {
    if(is_dir($target)){
        $files = glob( $target . '*', GLOB_MARK ); //GLOB_MARK adds a slash to directories returned

        foreach( $files as $file )
        {
            delete_files( $file );      
        }

        rmdir( $target );
    } elseif(is_file($target)) {
        unlink( $target );  
    }
}
?>
```

---

Then for debugging/troubleshooting:

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

as well as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`

Answer (score 0):

try to give correct path of file like

```
unlink('comics/'.$setComic); // use path with quote and concat php var to path
```

Comment: This hasn't affected anything unfortunately.

Comment: It should be. I'm trying to delete folder comics/0/ and supposedly everything inside /0/.

Comment: @alex494 You first need to delete all the files (or selected files) then remove the folder. `unlink` doesn't do both actions. Have a look at http://www.paulund.co.uk/php-delete-directory-and-files-in-directory and http://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=559 - Nota: `rmdir` only works on empty folders http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

Answer (score 0):

The line needs to be corrected:

```
unlink(comics/$setComic);
```

To:

```
unlink('comics/'.$setComic);
```

Also, check whether the path to image `/comics/` is correct.

Comment: /comics/ is a folder. I'm deleting another folder '0' inside it.